# Review Board installation of cryptography module

Tags: review-board

When installing Review Board, I found I needed a cryptography module.  While installing that, with the following command:

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade cryptography
```

I get the following error:

```
Searching for cryptography
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cryptography/
Best match: cryptography 1.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/a9/5b/a383b3a778609fe8177bd51307b5ebeee369b353550675353f46cb99c6f0/cryptography-1.4.
tar.gz#md5=a9763e3831cc7cdb402c028fac1ceb39
Processing cryptography-1.4.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-psOI1n/cryptography-1.4/setup.cfg
Running cryptography-1.4/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-psOI1n/cryptography-1.4/egg-dist-tmp-EEG_6Z
c/_cffi_backend.c:15:17: fatal error: ffi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <ffi.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Install libffi:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Comment: Note that I also needed to run the following, which was easily determined by using google:
    sudo apt-get install libssl-dev

Comment: Thank you, their FAQ really should get updated with this